Definition of impulse
As far as I'm concerned, impulse is defined as
$$\mathbf J=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\mathbf F\,dt\tag1$$
But, since Newton's second law of motion states that $\mathbf F=\frac{d\mathbf p}{dt}$, this just becomes
$$\mathbf p(t_2)-\mathbf p(t_1)\tag2$$
by the fundamental theorem of calculus. My question is: why would you write definition $(1)$ when definition $(2)$ is equivalent and much simpler?

What is the source of equation (1)?

@BobD https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_(physics)

What happens if you don't know $\mathbf{p}$ but you do know $\mathbf{F}$?

@KyleKanos I integrate $\mathbf F$. I don't see every physical formula given as a function of every possible physical quantity, you already know that $\mathbf F=\dot{\mathbf p}$.

@Elvis If you integrate $F$ over time, you get the impulse, yay! More pointedly: there are scenarios where you do not know the momentum but you do know the forces (and also vice versa). Having two equivalent formulae helps you in finding an answer in both cases.

Presumably you are talking about the net-impulse due to the net-force, as opposed to impulse of a force (not necessarily the net-force).

This is a soft question, so the best I can offer is a soft answer.
You are correct that the two forms are equivalent.  Either one could be taught as the definition.  The force based definition directly points to the value of the concept.  One could define a quantity which is the difference of any quantity of your choosing.  For example, the difference in positions is displacement.  So Declaring $J=p_2-p_1$ just doesn't show anything profound.  It just defines a new variable.  Declaring it as the integral of force shows that this particular subtraction does something useful.  It shows that this concept is useful for transforming force based problems into impulsive problems (which let one simply add and subtract momentums)

Yeah, this is pretty much what I was looking for. Thanks.


My question is: why would you write definition (1) when definition (2) is equivalent and much simpler?

Equation (2) is really useful if you know a priori the momenta as a function of time. In the case when you don't know $\mathbf{p}$ and you do know $\mathbf{F}$, then you must use Equation (1).
Hence, having two equivalent formulae helps you finding the impulse when you have one variable (momentum, force) and not the other.

I get this, thanks. Still, I don't get this: why is this particular formula written as a function of $\mathbf F$? I don't see every physical equation written in terms of every possible physical quantity, so why is there this preference here?

I don't know what "preference" you are seeing or what you intend by that statement in any way, but your Eq (1) is a definition of impulse. It is also fully equivalent to the definition of the impulse as the change in momentum between two times.


My question is: why would you write definition (1) when definition (2)
is equivalent and much simpler?

I wouldn't.
Although eq (1) defines the impulse of force where the force varies in time, eq (2) is in fact the more useful form because we are generally interested in the average impact force and measuring $\Delta v$ (which for constant mass gives us $\Delta p$) is generally far easier than determining how the impact force varies as a function of time, which would be necessary for evaluating eq (1).
Moreover the main value here is in determining the average impact force for use in the study of collisions (e.g., car collisions). For that purpose the following equation, which applies the work energy theorem (net work on an object equals its change in kinetic energy), can be useful to determine the average impact force.
$$F_{ave}d=-\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$
Where $F_{ave}$ is the average impact force, $d$ is the stopping distance and $v$ is the velocity just prior to impact.
Hope this helps.

Impulse has a meaning that is independent of the change-in-momentum.
(Update: By analogy, the work done by a force (not necessarily the net-force) has meaning independent of the change-in-kinetic-energy. That’s why we use Newton’s 2nd Law to derive the so-called Work-Energy Theorem (which involves the net-work not just the work of one of the forces).
What I originally posted is the Impulse-Momentum theorem (which involves the net-impulse not just the impulse of one of the forces.))
The connection is that 
it is the net-impulse (or the impulse of the net-force)
 that is equal (by way of Newton's 2nd Law)
to the change-in-momentum.
For a force $\vec F_1$, its impulse over a time interval from $t_A$ to $t_B$ is
the definite integral
$$\vec J_1=\int_{t_A}^{t_B} \vec F_1\ dt$$
Similarly,
$$\vec J_2=\int_{t_A}^{t_B} \vec F_2\ dt$$
When we have the net-force
$\vec F_{net} = \vec F_1 + \vec F_2 +\ldots \vec F_n$,
then the net-impulse is
\begin{align}
\vec J_{net}=\vec J_1 + \vec J_2  + \ldots + \vec J_n 
&=\int_{t_A}^{t_B}\left( \vec F_1 + \vec F_2  + \ldots + \vec F_n\right)\ dt\\
&=\int_{t_A}^{t_B}\left( \vec F_{net} \right)\ dt\\
&\stackrel{\smash{2ndLaw}}{=}\int_{t_A}^{t_B}\left( \frac{ d\vec p}{dt} \right)\ dt= \left(\vec p_B - \vec p_A\right)\\
\end{align}

I find that
$\int_{v_1}^{v_2} m \, dv=\int_{t_1}^{t_2} F \, dt$
is a useful equation which uses both of your impact properties.

The real reason is that physicists are very conservative and lazy to upgrade to newer ways of presenting old topics.
I mean, back when Newton was stating his laws of motion, the state of physics knowledge is so low that he had no good reason to pick one or the other. Prior to Newton, forces was already studied; a good treatment was by Stevinus. So, in a sense, Newton imported older knowledge by incorporating forces directly into his mechanics.
Just before the modern physics revolutions of relativity and quantum theory, Hertz started seeing that there is no place for forces in physics. But Hertz's textbook on classical mechanics was incomplete and really not a fully-fledged replacement for standard presentation. That is very sad.
After the modern physics revolutions, it is exceedingly clear that the concept of forces really had to die. Instead, you can use
$$\tag1\frac{\mathrm d\vec p}{\mathrm dt}=\vec F=-\vec\nabla H$$
to describe every use of forces in classical mechanics; either as a rate of change of momentum, or a gradient of the potential energies.
The terminology of impulse, and so forth, are relics of a by-gone era for $\Delta\vec p$; we really should not be defining new terms when "finite change in" is sufficient.
